# Maven Multi-module: Submodule as dependencies

Tags: java, maven-3

I have a multi-module project in maven and I created a main sub-module(which means that this sub-module has the main class). I add the other sub-modules into the main the sub-module(which is Submodule-0) as dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ProjectGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>Submodule-1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ProjectGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>Submodule-2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ProjectGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>Submodule-3</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I have Artifactory in my LAN and my maven settings.xml is configured to connect into the local Artifactory. In the PC where I installed the Artifactory this setup works fine but when I ran the setup in another computer(my laptop) it can't find the sub-modules libraries but I can see it in the Dependencies section of the project using Netbeans.

The Error Generated is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Submodule-0: Could not resolve dependencies for project ProjectGroupId:Submodule-0:jar:0.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at ProjectGroupId:Submodule-1:jar:0.0.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ProjectGroupId:Submodule-1:jar:0.0.1: Failure to find ProjectGroupId:MultiModule:pom:0.0.1 in http://192.168.10.136:8081/artifactory/libs-release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I hope you guys can help and if this is a duplicate question hope you guys can lead me in the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run a maven build with the goal "deploy" on the machine with Artifactory installed. With that the artifacts are uploaded to the Artifactory's repository and will be available for remote access.

Once you have a stable version you may want to take a look into the maven-release-stuff http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html

EDIT: 
Did you copy the settings.xml to the other machine?

Comment: Yes they have the same settings.xml but except in the machine with Artifactory which is set to localhost instead of an specific IP

Comment: Ok, and did you run the deploy build? Btw, does Artifactory have some kind of webinterface to check the existance of an artifact?

Comment: This might be another question but what is the difference between a submodule and an external maven project because the external maven projects that I have added in the dependencies has no problems at all but the sub-modules have problems in compiling

Comment: If you include them as a dependency there is no difference concerning retrieval from a repository. Did you deploy the external maven project?

Comment: I didn't deploy the external maven project but instead clone a repository into the machine with no Artifactory

Comment: hmm, why do you clone the repository? That's Artifactory for -> to provide a central repository for all your (maven) clients? And I think your submodule artifacts are neither part of that cloned repository nor uploaded to Artifactory, so they can't be found...

Comment: We just thought to better clone the repository so that all developers can see that project in their machines.

Comment: Yes this one works `mvn deploy` or just `mvn install` for local deployment, thanks for the answer